# Cassandra Data Distribution across node

Tags: database, cassandra, distribution, partitioning, database-administration

I have 4 nodes cassandra cluster. data of event_attr_str table is not distributed across nodes. 3. node have much more data according to the other nodes.

I applied repair and clenaup for this table but no remedy. Data is not distributed across nodes

How can I distribute this data across nodes ?

1. node: 1.4T    event_attr_str-d81723700a6111e786e8d5b69603026f
2. node: 1.4T    event_attr_str-d81723700a6111e786e8d5b69603026f
3. node: 2.4T    event_attr_str-d81723700a6111e786e8d5b69603026f
4. ndoe: 1.2T    event_attr_str-d81723700a6111e786e8d5b69603026f

Comment: have you perform full repair ?

Comment: Disclaimer: ***without any other knowledge of your setup,*** it looks like you have a "hotspot" in your data. that is, a large number of your primary keys are hashed to the same token_range and thus are being stored on the same node. What is your RF?

Comment: @UttamKasundara yes did it but nothing changed

Comment: @LHWizard cluster 'replication_factor': '2'

Answer (score 0):

Tuning a multi-node Cassandra cluster is more art than science.  I'm still a beginner at this too.  I'm currently watching my little dev cluster and trying to learn about the issues we might bump into in production. I've found this resource to be a good starting point for learning about clustering at the table level:

https://thelastpickle.com/blog/2019/02/21/set-up-a-cluster-with-even-token-distribution.html